# I can't display TableView in added subview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController named LiveMatchVC. I want to show another ViewController(named **LiveMatchMomentsVC** and it has a **TableView**) in LiveMatchVC.

I added a subview and I displayed LiveMatchMomentsVC in LiveMatchVC, but I can't view the TableView of the LiveMatchMoments in LiveMatchVC.

My codes and screenshots are as below.

How can I solve this problem?

[White area is my TableView in LiveMatchMomentsVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxfRb.png)

**LiveMatchVC Codes**

class LiveMatchVC: UIViewController {

```
//---------Outlets-----------
@IBOutlet weak var imgLiveMatchScoreBG: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var openLeft: UIBarButtonItem!

    let titleCont1 = TZSegmentedControl(sectionTitles: ["Maç Raporu","Canlı Anlatım", "Önemli Olaylar", "İstatistikler", "Kadrolar" ])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let liveMatchMomentsVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LiveMatchMomentsVC") as! LiveMatchMomentsVC

        titleCont1.indexChangeBlock = { (index) in

            if self.titleCont1.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                self.view.addSubview(liveMatchMomentsVC.view)
                liveMatchMomentsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.imgLiveMatchScoreBG.frame.height+self.titleCont1.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-44)

                self.addChildViewController(liveMatchMomentsVC)
                self.view.addSubview(liveMatchMomentsVC.view)
                self.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            }

        }
}
}
```

**LiveMatchMomentsVC Codes**

import UIKit

class LiveMatchMomentsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblLiveMatch: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 15

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MatchEvent", for: indexPath) as! MatchEventTableViewCell

    cell.lblMatchEventTime.text = "69"
    cell.lblMatchEvent.text = "Goal. Juraj Kucka"

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: You are adding the moments subview twice and you need to call `liveMatchMomentsVC.didMove(toParentViewController:self)` not `self.didMove..`;

Comment: Thank you for your response but the problem still continue. I couldn't solve with this method.

Comment: Have you  set constraints on your table view?  Have you set the table view's datasource and delegate properties in Interface Builder?